# NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString() returns nil for ar-SA locale

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to format `UILabel` text for selected locale using `NSNumberFormatter` for `NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle` and setting up locale for the formatter as `ar-SA`.

When `UILabel` text has large numbers that are converted to E notation(scientific notation) for example- "1e9", "2.3456e24" etc. the `numberFromString()` returns `nil` for `ar-SA` locale. However, it works fine for other locales.

```
@IBOutlet weak var displayText: UILabel!

let format = NSNumberFormatter()
format.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
format.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: language)// where language = "ar-SA" or "en-US" or "de-DE"
format.maximumFractionDigits = 16  

var result =  displayText.text! // result = "1e9" or "2.3456e24" 
guard let number = format.numberFromString(result), let string = format.stringFromNumber(number) else {
        displayText.text = "Error"
        return
    }
result = string
```

How to fix this? Is there any restriction with `ar-SA` locale and E notations together?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the number to "en" locale and after that you convert the resulting string to "ar_SA" locale. Apparently, the "ar_SA" locale does not recognize the "e" notation.

```
let format = NSNumberFormatter()
format.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
format.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en")
format.maximumFractionDigits = 16

    var result = displayText.text!
    guard let number = format.numberFromString(result), let string = format.stringFromNumber(number) else {
        return
    }

    format.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar_SA")
    guard let string2 = format.stringFromNumber(number) else {
        return
    }
    result = string2
```

Comment: This seems to be the right approach to convert to number with default locale or "en" but it did not work for all the conversions between locales. So, i am only converting the string to number with default locale if there is guard fails with any particular locale which happens to be only "ar-SA" in my case. Thanks for the help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you format an `NSNumber` using an `NSNumberFormatter` with scientific style and an Arabic locale, you will see that a number such as `2.3456e24` would need to be entered as `٢٫٣٤٥٦اس٢٤`.

Trying to parse `2.3456e24` will only work on locales that use the digits `0-9`, a period, and `e` or `E` for the exponent.

If you wish to allow a user to enter numbers in various formats, you will need to try your number formatter with multiple locales. Start with the default locale. If that gives back a `nil` number, try another locale. Try as many locales as you wish to support.

Comment: While testing the changes as per suggestions by Kaique , i realized that iterating over all supported locales and trying number formatter with  can be the best thing to do. But right now, i am sticking up with solution as in my above comment. Thanks though @rmaddy :)